# Biopython to extract base calls at a list of positions

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I have a list of positions of interest eg:

```
10
20
1000
4000000
```

I want to extract the base call at these positions from a fasta file using biopython.

This is what I have tried:

```
query_dic ={}
with open(line) as pos_file:
    for x in pos_file:
        for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(query_file, "fasta"):
            nuc = seq_record[x] 
            query_dic[x]=nuc
```

The error message says 'invalid index' - what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely some of the sequences are not long enough to have that many letters, and thus the larger indexes are invalid.

You might consider modifying the final loop to something like this:

```
if len(seq_record) > x:
    nuc = seq_record[x]
else:
    nuc = None
query_dic[x] = nuc
```